# Azure Document AI opensource alternative

Tags: azure, ocr

is there any open-source alternative to Azure Document AI where we can train custom extraction models just like in Azure? currently, I'm using Azure but in the custom extraction models the OCR is misreading some characters, so I wanted to know if is there any open-source alternative so I can train the model more accurately

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives, let u put down a few github repos for you

Tesseract is an open-source OCR engine developed by Google
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

OCRopus is an OCR (Optical Character Recognition) system

https://github.com/ocropus-archive/DUP-ocropy

Kraken is an OCR engine for document analysis and text extraction

https://github.com/uber/kraken